# "java: package org.apache.cordova does not exist" when compiling phonegap project template in Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I am New to Android and phonegap development, recently i follow the instruction from various internet blog and trying to setup phonegap with android studio. After i successfully install and follow all the settings (Env variable staff...etc), and after i import phonegap project into android studio, i have the following error message while trying to build the project:

```
java: package org.apache.cordova does not exist

java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class DroidGap

java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.demo.androidstudio.ProjectTemplate

java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.demo.androidstudio.ProjectTemplate

java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

What should i do next?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: make sure you have cordova jar in libs directory and also have `libs/cordova.jar` in dependency block. Or Better to include your project structure, screenshot of ide and build.gradle files so one can answer quickly .

Comment: @pyus13 Where can I find the cordova.jar file?

Comment: get cordova jar from here using npm. You can get the latest version via npm: https://npmjs.org/package/cordova

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest version of android from https://www.apache.org/dist/cordova/platforms/
2. Navigate to the Android package's / framework directory and run `ant ja` It Cordova Creates the .jar file
3. Copy the local.properties file from your CLI cordova project created (To fix Error: build.xml:42: You need to create the file 'local.properties’).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to the other one but with some essential differences:

```
1. Download the latest version of android from https://www.apache.org/dist/cordova/platforms/
2. Navigate to the Android package's / framework directory 
3. run 'android update project -p .'
4. then run `ant jar`
5. Copy cordova-*.jar file into your /libs/ folder
```