# Error compiling cordova 4 on Android Studio: package org.apache.cordova does not exist

Tags: cordova, android-studio

I'm new with cordova and I'm not familiarized with Android Studio or Android development.
I'm compiling the cordova 4.3 project on Android Studio but it doesn't work. I get the error above in the title.
I just found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011405/java-package-org-apache-cordova-does-not-exist-when-compiling-phonegap-projec) and I assume by the comments that I need  the cordova.jar and include it in dependency block but I don't understand how to do it.
Somebody can give a small explanation about doing that or any other way?
Thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you not import Cordova-lib project into your android project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should elaborate something. You are not specifying anything here.

Comment: there are no explanation.